# Div cut into the mask

Tags: css, html

I have a div which is the mask. The second div should be cut into the mask transparent. If the background color green, so that the div should be green

```
<body style="background:green;">
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;background:red;z-index:501;"></div>
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;background:blue;position:absolute;z-index:502;"></div>
<!-- I want to make the second div in the body-color that is the green color -->
​
```

Can you help me somehow? Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/RYKFQ/2/

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense, what are you trying to achieve? Created jsfiddle for testing purposes (http://jsfiddle.net/RYKFQ/)

Comment: I can see a red and a blue div, but no clear relationship, and nothing green. What is your question? Can you provide more info in the example? 

Update: Am I correct in understanding that you want the second of your two DIV's to make part of the first one transparent? So that you can see a green background if the blue overlaps the red?

Answer (score 0):

How about this: Set the opacity of the color as you desire in the second Div.Play around the opacity to get the desired masking effect. Put the second div in a parent DIV that has the background color you desire. May be the following fiddle might help you. Good Luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/AFckr/

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Replace `background:blue;` with `background:none;`

That will still put the `div` in front of the background. You can put anything in there and the browser will let the background shine through.

Answer (score 0):

If you want see body backgound in second div you can use for example:

```
body, div.second {background: url("some_image.png") 0 0 fixed}
```

But, this is only trick and doesn't make first div transparent.